# Extract value between HTML tags from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I got some problem. I tried to know how to do but... nothing... Im doing something wrong and i dont know what...

I have a ajax request to JSON.

I receive some properties with the values. One  of them is with HTML inside:

```
"<p>Title</p>
<p>Category</p>
<p>First p.</p>
<p>Second p.</p>"
```

I would like to get the "Title" in another variable and the "Category" in another variable. The "first p" and the "second p" in another variable.

I did something like this, but nothing happen.

```
tTitle = $(textThumb).find("p:nth-child(0)").html();
tCat = $(textThumb).find("p:nth-child(1)").html();
tText = $(textThumb).remove("p:nth-child(0)","p:nth-child(1)").html();
```

All of them became undefined.

If I print **textThumb** and the other values from other parameters are also ok, is just here the problem that i dont know how to think about it

Thanks,.

Comment: CSS indices are one-based, so you probably want `p:nth-child(1)` and `p:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: also, you want to filter, not find. there isn't a parent element to find from.

Comment: The point is that the HTML is not printer yet, is inside an array. If was printed is not a problem, but i would like to first separate in variables and after print on the html. I tried in on-based, but nothing. tTitle, tCat and tText came undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways to go about whatever you are doing besides returning JSON with html as values - that said, what you need to do is put a string with one parent node into the jQuery selector.

```
$('<div><p>Hi</p><p>Hi Again</p></div>').find('p').eq(0).text() // 'Hi!'
```

or with nth-child() selector (which should start at 1)

```
$('<div><p>Hi</p><p>Hi Again</p></div>').find('p:nth-child(1)').text() // 'Hi!'
```

In your case `$('<div>'+textThumb+'</div>')` ...

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var $p = $(textThumb).filter("p"),
    tTitle = $p.eq(0).text(),
    tCat = $p.eq(1).text();
```

The main thing is to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) rather than [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) because the latter looks for elements that are descendants but the elements you want are at the top level.

> *"The "first p" and the "second p" in another variable."*

If you mean that you want the text from both of those paragraphs into the same variable then perhaps:

```
var tText = $p.slice(2).text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g39Gm/

Comment: This is working good, now understand the difference between filter and find. True that p tags are the first element. It was inside a div, was more properly use find may i think?

Answer (score 1):

```
var tree = $(textThumb);
tTitle = tree[0].innerText;
tCat = tree[1].innerText;
tText = tree[2].innerText + tree[3].innerText
```

Comment: This just define tTile, the others remain undefined. Thanks. I didnt know this way.